# Doesn't wait for result of messageBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, messagebox

When catching a unhandled exception in a client application currently in user testing I made a code like this.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    Current.Shutdown();
}
```

But the message box only appears very quickly and then the program shuts down. WHy doesn't the code wait for result to be apparent. How would I do that?

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  Use the debugger to find out what else is going on.

Comment: use null in start of message box parameter, this will make message box a independent and top level interface.

Comment: This is happening on startup, I guess that could be the problem. It's done before mainWindow is resolved.

Comment: We'll need more to go on than that.  The code you posted (other than `Current.Shutdown()`, I don't know what `Current` is) works fine (message box shows before any window is created and doesn't exit before pressing OK).

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue. Problem is that exception is thrown before the main window is displayed and thus there is no Window to display the message box on. Swamy's answer mere forced a time delay so that the window can be initialized. IMO not too elegant. Found a better solution [here][WPF MessageBox not waiting for result [WPF NotifyIcon]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403098/wpf-messagebox-not-waiting-for-result-wpf-notifyicon).

Just specify the `MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly` in the `MessageBox.Show(....) method`.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation to [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox) class:

> Message boxes always have an owner window. By default, the owner of a message box is the window that is currently active in an application at the time that a message box is opened. However, you can specify another owner for the [`Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window) by using one of several [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox.show) overloads. For more information about owner windows, see [`Window.Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner).

Thus your problem is really similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5923188/572834) where the application exists before message box is dismissed by the user.

The first thing to try is to pass `null` as `Window` parameter.

```
MessageBox.Show(null, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

If you have an instance of `Window` class, for example your main window object, pass it instead of `null`:

```
MessageBox.Show(mainWindow, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

If you are currently in any of the main window methods, you can pass `this` as the Window:

```
MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

---

Use `null` only in case where there's no main window object available at this time.

Look at [MessageBox sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=160023). You should be able to see the difference between the cases where `this` is passed as the owner window and where `null` is passed.

Comment: OK null only throws a null reference exception but I was wondering if I the owning window currently hasn't had the Show() methods on it call is it still good as a proper owner?

Comment: Yes, the owner window can be not visible on the screen.

Comment: When using `null` it may be ambiguous which function you want to call. To make it explicit, you can cast `null` to `Window` or create a local variable `Window owner = null` and use `owner` variable as the parameter to `Show`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using this code inside the script or actual .net application?
You are missing "s" in message box button.
you should writte code like this:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("My new exception");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

If this will not work you should look at the code that throws your exception for further debugging...

Comment: I guess your code is from Windows Forms because MessageBoxButton is correct and the result is MessageBoxResult. Tried that though but didn't change anything. I think this has to do with me instancing this messagebox before the mainwindow is created.

Comment: It's nice to have two different `MessageBox` classes doing roughly the same: `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` and `System.Windows.MessageBox`. I consider it quite confusing, in particular when asking questions. Though the question is tagged with `wpf` which implies `System.Windows.MessageBox` is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question, but probably below answer may hep some one else,

I had the same situation where I wanted to show the Message box before the Main window is created, and in My case too , the message Box was disappearing Before I click on OK and application would shut down.

I am using async and awaits and adding a delay as low as 10 millisecond fixed the problem for me.(As the main window is loaded by that time)

```
await Task.Delay(10);
if (MessageBox.Show(MainWindow, "Message", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
    Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Probably for non Async methods Thread.Sleep could also work (not tried).

Answer (score 0):

Before any Window is shown in a not async Methode, this solved the Problem for me:

```
 if (Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("test", "Fehler", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)).Result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
 {
     Environment.Exit(1);
 }
```